# How do I make the innerHTML of a block-level element appear in the QTip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I am using the QTip javascript library on my web page. When the user clicks on a link (which I have made to be block level), a QTip appears.

I have hidden the inner text of the links with `text-indent: -10000px;`. The text will appear in the QTip that appears after clicking on the link.

I cannot store this text in the title attribute since the title attribute contains other data.

How do I use the QTip API to grab the innerHTML of the element being clicked on? I haven't found it in their documentation yet: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/

I have tried

```
content: {
    text: $(this).html(),
}
```

to no avail. Thanks.

---

Additionally, it might be useful to know that another QTip appears when the user hovers over the link. The content for this other QTip is stored in the link's title attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(function($) {
    var $link = $('yourLink'),
        value = $link.html();

    $(function() {
        $link.qtip({
            content: {
                text: value
            }
        });
    });        
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks! Doing var $link = $('yourLink'),
        value = $link.html(); did the trick.